# Get the URL of an ad in LinkedIn Marketing API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am wokring in the linked in marketing api to create a tool letting use report on our ads. One thing I need is the URL of the ads to show stats per destination.

I am not entirely sure which part of the ad this is tied to, but I assumed it is tied to creative.

In the documentation it shows an example request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/{ID}
```

and it provides a result with a click URI

```
{
    {
        "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:326050844",
        "id": 104748094,
        "review": {
            "reviewStatus": "PENDING"
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "type": "TEXT_AD",
        "variables": {
            "clickUri": "http://www.dundermifflin.com",
            "data": {
                "com.linkedin.ads.TextAdCreativeVariables": {
                    "imageId": "",
                    "text": "Out of paper. Out of stock. There's friendly faces around the block.",
                    "title": "People Person's Paper People"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I submit a request it does not give me this information. My request (id changed for privacy of clients)

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/12345678
```

returns with

```
{  
   "reference":"urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "variables":{  
      "data":{  
         "com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables":{  
            "activity":"urn:li:activity:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "share":"urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "directSponsoredContent":true
         }
      }
   },
   "changeAuditStamps":{  
      "created":{  
         "time":1499978379000
      },
      "lastModified":{  
         "time":1518332188000
      }
   },
   "review":{  
      "reviewStatus":"AUTO_APPROVED"
   },
   "campaign":"urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:xxxxxxxxx",
   "servingStatuses":[  
      "RUNNABLE"
   ],
   "id":12345678,
   "type":"SPONSORED_STATUS_UPDATE",
   "version":{  
      "versionTag":"3"
   },
   "status":"ACTIVE"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that some creatives simply do not have a clickURI.

One example of this is the LinkedIn Lead Gen Form system. Your ad forwards into a lead generation system created in LinkedIn rather than to a specified URL.